# Oracle SQL Regex - Pass Variable Name in Regex Query

Tags: sql, regex, oracle

I want to use a variable in my Oracle SQL query which is using regex for filtering. The original query works fine when I hardcode the desired string ("TKelly") in the SQL query:

```
SELECT Custom_Unique_Name from USERS
WHERE REGEXP_LIKE (Custom_Unique_Name, '^TKelly[^A-Za-z][0-9]*')
```

Output:

```
CUSTOM_UNIQUE_NAME
------------------
TKelly1
TKelly3
TKelly2
```

However, when I am trying to use a variable in the same query, it does not quite work the same way.

```
variable vname varchar2(20)
exec :vname := 'TKelly';

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SELECT Custom_Unique_Name from USERS
WHERE REGEXP_LIKE (Custom_Unique_Name, '^'|| :vname || [^A-Za-z][0-9]'*');
```

Output:

```
ORA-00936: missing expression
00936. 00000 -  "missing expression"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing single quotes for the rest of the regular expression:

```
WHERE REGEXP_LIKE(Custom_Unique_Name,
                  '^'|| :vname || '[^A-Za-z][0-9]*'
                 );
```